# Понятие типов данных в С++

Tags: c++

Решил изучить С++. Дошёл типа char:

*Символьные типы

В C++ есть следующие символьные типы данных:
char: представляет один символ в кодировке ASCII. Занимает в памяти 1 байт (8 бит). Может хранить любое значение из диапазона от -128 до 127, либо от 0 до 255

wchar_t: представляет расширенный символ. На Windows занимает в памяти 2 байта (16 бит), на Linux - 4 байта (32 бита). Может хранить любой значение из диапазона от 0 до 65 535 (при 2 байтах), либо от 0 до 4 294 967 295 (для 4 байт)

char8_t: представляет один символ в кодировке Unicode. Занимает в памяти 1 байт. Может хранить любой значение из диапазона от 0 до 256
char16_t: представляет один символ в кодировке Unicode. Занимает в памяти 2 байта (16 бит). Может хранить любой значение из диапазона от 0 до 65 535

char32_t: представляет один символ в кодировке Unicode. Занимает в памяти 4 байта (32 бита). Может хранить любой значение из диапазона от 0 до 4 294 967 295*

**Так как я перешёл с Java, то char - символьный тип. На сайте указано что в с++ это тоже сивольный тип. Но зачем этому символьному типу диапазон, если он может принимать один символ в системе Unicode?**

Comment: В C++ символ и целое число - одно и то же. Например, `char` используется и как символ ASCII, и как однобайтовое знаковое целое.